# std::getline partially reads first and last line and sets eof-bit

Tags: c++, csv, eof, getline

I need to read csv-files with C++: the first line of the file contains all column titles, the remaining lines contain floating point data (examples below, files have been shrunk down).

A few files have issues, I'm using the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// Compiled and testen on with Clang++ on Ubuntu 14.04
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::ifstream in;
    in.open(argv[1]);

    if(!in.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open file: " << argv[1] << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string buff;
    std::getline(in, buff);
    while(!in.eof()) {
        std::cout << buff << "\n";
        getline(in, buff);
    }

    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

For most files this runs okay, reading one line each iteration; example of a 'good' file:

```
Time,Smile,AU04,AU02,AU15,Trackerfail,AU18,AU09,negAU12,AU10,Expressive,Unilateral_LAU12,Unilateral_RAU12,AU14,Unilateral_LAU14,Unilateral_RAU14,AU05,AU17,AU26,Forward,Backward
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,33.333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,20.0
0.3,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,33.333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,33.333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,16.667,0.0
58.3,50.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,33.333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
62.4,33.333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,20.0
```

Some files go crazy and set the eof-bit after the first `getline`. After this first read, `buff` contains part of the first line and part of the last line; example of a 'bad' file:

```
Time,Smile,AU04,AU02,AU15,Trackerfail,AU18,AU09,negAU12,AU10,Occlusion,Expressive,Unilateral_LAU12,Unilateral_RAU12,AU14,Unilateral_LAU14,Unilateral_RAU14,AU05,Au17,AU57,AU58
0,0,0,0,0,16.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0.3,0,0,0,0,33.333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1.3,0,0,0,0,16.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
57.9,66.667,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
60.3,33.333,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

And the contents of `buff` after one call to `getline`:

```
Time,Smile,AU04,AU02,AU15,Trackerfail,AU18,AU09,negAU12,AU10,Occlusion,Expressive,Unilateral_LAU12,Unilateral_RAU12,AU14,Unilateral_LAU14,Unilateral_RA60.3,33.333,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

As you can see, the first line gets mixed with the last line. I can't figure out what's going wrong. Each line ends with a `\n`, the file ends with an empty `\n`.

I suppose my question is: why does `getline` skip to end-of-file while mixing the first and last line for some of the files while others work fine?

**Edit:** I need to convert a big dataset to a new, more consistent format. The current format is full of inconsistencies (using `0` and `0.0` or `AU17` and `Au17`). Still, these formatting problems should not affect simply reading the file, right?

**Edit2:**

`cat -v -e -t` on a good file:

```
Time,Smile,AU04,AU02,AU15,Trackerfail,AU18,AU09,negAU12,AU10,Expressive,Unilateral_LAU12,Unilateral_RAU12,AU14,Unilateral_LAU14,AU05,AU17,AU26,Forward,Backward^M$
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,66.667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0^M$
0.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,33.333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0^M$
etc...
```

`cat -v -e -t` on a bad file:

```
Time,Smile,AU04,AU02,AU15,Trackerfail,AU18,AU09,negAU12,AU10,Occlusion,Expressive,Unilateral_LAU12,Unilateral_RAU12,AU14,Unilateral_LAU14,Unilateral_RAU14,AU05,Au17,AU57,AU58^M0,0,0,0,0,16.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M0.3,0,0,0,0,33.333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M1.3,0,0,0,0,16.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M1.4,0,0,0,0,33.333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M1.8,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0^M2.8,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M3,0,0,0,0,33.333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M31,0,0,0,0,33.333,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M31.1,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M31.2,0,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M31.4,0,0,33.333,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M31.5,0,0,33.333,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,50,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M32,0,0,33.333,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,50,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25^M32.1,0,0,33.333,0,83.333,0,0,0,0,50,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25^M32.2,0,0,33.333,0,83.333,0,0,0,0,25,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25^M32.4,0,0,33.333,0,83.333,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25^M32.7,0,0,33.333,0,83.333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25^M33,0,0,33.333,0,83.333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M33.5,0,0,0,0,83.333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M33.9,0,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M55,33.333,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M55.2,66.667,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M55.8,100,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M56.8,100,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25^M57.4,66.667,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25^M57.8,66.667,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M57.9,66.667,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0^M60.3,33.333,0,0,0,66.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Seems like a big difference, how can I solve this?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but instead of two `std::getline` calls, why not simple rely on the fact that `std::getline` (like just about all other stream functions) return the actual stream reference, and do e.g. `while (std::getline(...))`?

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure that there's nothing other wrong with the file? You only check for end-of-file and not other errors in your loop. There's no hidden (unprintable) characters inside the faulty files? Is it always problems with the same files?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The reason for that in this snippet of code is that I wanted to quickly check different bits: eof, fail, bad. But in my application's code I'm doing it as you suggested. **Edit:** It never reaches inside the loop, eof-bit gets set immediately; checking for fail-bit results in a single iteration. And yes it's always on the same files, which makes it very curious! I have checked for `\r` and `\c` characters but there are none in the files.

Comment: What is the output of ``cat -v -e -t <your_file>``? I suspect @Joachim Pileborg is correct.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Because then if there's CTRL-Z (ASCII `0x1a`) in the text it will act as a end-of-file too. Have you checked the file in a hex-editor?

Comment: @AmiTavory I've added the output of those commands to the question. It seems that Joachim was correct. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, but it seems like there are some big differences between good and bad files that were not visible with a normal text editor.

Comment: That `^M` indicates a line-ending problem, it's the carriage-return character.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You were right suspecting unprintable characters messing up the files. The 'faulty' files were made on a Mac OS system and messed up the reads. Should you post your comments as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the files are missing the newline character, and instead have only the carriage-return characters (which is equal to `^M` or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>).

You can fix it by using using `cat` with the file, and piping to `tr` to translate the carriage-return to a newline:

```
$ cat your-file | tr '\r' '\n' > your-file-fixed
```

---

After seeing your comment about the files coming from Max OS, I assume that it's the old pre-OSX versions, when the newline on Mac OS was just a single carriage-return.

Comment: According to Sublime Text, they are made on Mac OS 9. Again, thanks for helping!